# Using ampersand in sed

Tags: regex, csv, sed

I have a csv file full of lines like the following:

```
Aity Chel Jenni,Hendaland 229,2591 TE Amsterdam
```

I want to create a sed pattern for in an automated batch script that changes the info in this kind of formatting into the following formatting:

```
Aity Chel Jenni,Hendaland 30,2591 TE, Amsterdam
```

With a bit of research, I found out that I had to create a regex, then use an ampersand (&) character to have it change things around using the & to define the location of the regex.

I have tried the following:

```
 sed 's/([1-9] [A-Z]{2}/&,/' file1 >file2
```

And have been trying variants of that trying to get the regexes down, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Am I making a mistake in the usage of the ampersand or is my regex wrong?
Reading through the internet I can't seem to wrap my head around this function, can someone give me any examples/explain to me how to properly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying

```
sed 's/([1-9] [A-Z]{2}/&,/' file1 >file2
       ^
```

But you don't have to capture with `()` to use `&`. Instead, just say:

```
sed 's/[1-9] [A-Z]\{2\}/&,/' file
```

Note you need to escape the elements in the `{ }` quantifier, unless you use `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/[1-9] [A-Z]{2}/&,/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sed -r 's:[0-9] [A-Z]{2}\b:&,:' file > out
```

About your own pattern, you're missing the closing parenthesis. And, iirc, you need to escape `(` inside sed patterns to not match them literally.

The `-r` option enabled `sed` to use extended regex, which provides the `{2}` expansion.